# How some sites run javascript on the client side of opera mini

Tags: javascript, animation, client-side, opera-mini

I see some websites (eg. google, amazon, instagram, etc) run javascript and even animations on the client side of opera mini.

How do they achieve this knowing that opera mini has repeatedly stated that it executes javascript on its server side?

Edit: I have acknowledged above that opera mini executes javascript on opera mini servers.
My question is how do websites like amazon.com search bar appear to execute javascript right there on the client side instead of going through the operamini servers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460788/how-can-opera-mini-runs-javascript-only-in-the-server-instead-the-device "How can Opera-mini runs javascript only in the server instead the device?
"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can Opera-mini runs javascript only in the server instead the device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460788/how-can-opera-mini-runs-javascript-only-in-the-server-instead-the-device)